# SQL How to find the value but as a percentage

Tags: sql, formula, payment, percentage

I am looking to find the value, in percentage, per card and bank transaction. This would need to be year to date, as the table provides data over several years.

The DBMS is IOMETE

An example is

| Payment | Amount | Transaction Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Payment1 | 10 | Card |
| Payment2 | 10 | Card |
| Payment3 | 10 | Card |
| Payment4 | 10 | Card |
| Payment5 | 500 | Bank |

Outcome

| Transaction Type | Payment Value | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Card | 7.41% | 80.00% |
| Bank | 92.59% | 20.00% |

I would need to know how to union the query with another query that has filtered my data down. Here is what I have so far:

```
WITH cute AS (
SELECT payment_method, date(created_at), status
FROM production.payments
WHERE created_at >= ‘2023-01-01’
  and payment_method != ‘cash’
  and status != ‘failed’
)
SELECT payment_method,
round (count (*) / sum(count(*)) over () * 100 ,2) as pct_of_total
from CTE
group by payment_method
```

Comment: Hi - what have you already attempted?  The purpose of StackOverflow is not really to just ask the community to do all of your work for you - there's an expectation that you've already made some attempts yourself (and that you show those attempts) so that others can guide you on where you're perhaps going astray, and you can ultimately get to a final solution yourself

Comment: Hi - I am new to sql, and I have researched many questions on this site, where someone asks a question, with no work, and people show them how to write the code. This is why there is no work/attempts because what I have attempted to do makes no sense, so I am lost and looking for assistance. I have a query that has filtered down my table, but now I need assistance with a subquery that would produce the above results.

Comment: @EAS Hi! I was looking at your edit summary and saw that the first version of the question actually included the code you'd tried, while the current version doesn't. It's better to keep the code example in your question, even if it doesn't work - after all, that's how we know what to help you with!